# Can I upload all images to jupyter at once?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've started Jupyter server on my localhost. 
Right now I need to upload my dataset. 
I have created new folder in the datasets directory. 
I've choosed images I want to upload and jupyter asks me to press Upload button for each image now. 
My dataset is a big one, so I need to upload all images without pressing Upload button for the whole day. 
Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to put folder with dataset into Jupyter root + needed path.
It will be available automatically.